# How to 'cast' a string from appsettings.json to a static class field value

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings, jsonparser

I'm investigating storing policies in `appsettings.json`.  In `Startup.cs`, I have:

```
var policies = Configuration.GetSection(OperationPolicies.Name).Get<OperationPolicies>();
```

to import the policies, based on [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).  The ClaimType value will be one of the field names from the `[ClaimTypes][2]` class from
System.Security.Claims as shown in the appsetting.json, below.  What I would like to do is convert the field name in the config file to the matching field value from ClaimTypes.  Is there an elegant way to do this as part of the JSON parsing or is it just parse to strings then use Reflection to get the value?

`OperationPolicies.cs`

```
public class OperationPolicies
{
    public const string Name = "OperationPolicies";

    public OperationPolicy[] Policies { get; set; }
}
```

`OperationPolicy.cs`

```
public class OperationPolicy
{
    public string Policy { get; set; }
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; }
}
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "OperationPolicies": {
    "Policies": [
      {
        "Policy": "AdminOnly",
        "ClaimType": "Role",
        "ClaimValue": "Admin"
      },
      {
        "Policy": "AppAdminOnly",
        "ClaimType": "GroupSid",
        "ClaimValue": "S-1-5-21-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my fellow directors here at Stack, David Haney, did a great write up on this: https://www.davidhaney.io/net-core-mvc-access-appsettings-json/

In his example he had this class

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public const string SectionName = "MySettings";

    public string WebDomain { get; set; }
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And mapped it from his config using this code in startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
        services.AddOptions();
        // Hook our MyOptions class up to the corresponding appsettings section
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(MyOptions.SectionName));
}
```

So I think you are a good amount of the way there, here is how it should apply to yours

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
        services.Configure<List<OperationPolicy>>(Configuration.GetSection("OperationPolicies:Policies"));
...
}
```

You could also try mapping it to your OperationPolicies policy class, but that seems needless.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
        services.Configure<OperationPolicies>(Configuration.GetSection("OperationPolicies"));
...
}
```

From there you can inject it into the pipeline or do whatever operations you need.